# Fetch and update records while looping through an array in IONIC3

Tags: javascript, angular, sqlite, asynchronous, ionic3

I am working on a store management project and I got hooked here for some days now.
I am trying to add sale items to saleItem table then update quantity left and quantity sold in both product and supplyItem table.

The code below work fine if there is no duplicate product in the itemList i.e if a product is not added more than once but only update the last product if duplicate product is added.

Is there anything I need to know about making asynchronous request to IONIC SQLite?

```
/**
* Save saleItems, update quantity left in product table and update quantity sold and quantity left in supplyItem table
**/
addSaleItems(saleID, store){
try{
/*this.itemList is an array containing all informations required
  loop through Items */
  this.itemList.forEach((item) => {
    /*insert save items*/
    let query = "INSERT INTO SaleItem (";
    query += "Name, IsActive, TheSale, TheProduct, BatchNo, UnitPrice, Total, TotalCostPrice, Profit_Loss, Quantity";
    query += ") VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    let data = [item.TheProductName,'true',saleID,item.TheProduct,item.BatchNo,item.UnitPrice,item.Total,item.TotalCostPrice,item.Profit_Loss,item.Quantity];

    this.database.noRetValQuery(query, data).then((retval) => {

      let prod_q = "SELECT Quantity FROM Product WHERE ID = ?";
      let prod_d = [item.TheProductID]
      /* Get quantity of that particular item left in product table */
      this.database.retValQuery(prod_q, prod_d).then((prodRetVal) => {
        let leftPro = Number(prodRetVal[0].Quantity) - Number(item.Quantity);
        let prod_data = [leftPro, item.TheProductID];
        return prod_data;
      })
      .then((prod_data) => {
        /*Update quantity left in product table*/
        let prod_query = "UPDATE Product SET Quantity = ? WHERE ID = ?";
        this.database.noRetValQuery(prod_query, prod_data).then((retval) => { });
      })

       /* Get QuantitySold and QuantityLeft of that particular item left in SupplyItem table */
      let queryPro = "SELECT QuantitySold, QuantityLeft FROM SupplyItem WHERE BatchNo = ? AND TheProduct = ? AND TheStore = ? LIMIT 1";
      let dataPro = [item.BatchNo, item.TheProductID, store];
      this.database.retValQuery(queryPro, dataPro).then((saleRetVal) => {
        let qtyS = Number(saleRetVal[0].QuantitySold) + Number(item.Quantity);
        let qtyL = Number(saleRetVal[0].QuantityLeft) - Number(item.Quantity);
        let sup_data = [qtyL, qtyS, item.BatchNo, item.TheProductID];
        return sup_data;
      }).then((sup_data) => {
        /*Update Supply Items*/
        let sup_query = "UPDATE SupplyItem SET QuantityLeft = ?, QuantitySold = ? WHERE BatchNo = ? AND TheProduct = ?";
        this.database.noRetValQuery(sup_query, sup_data).then((retval) => { })
      });
    });
  });
} finally {
  this.dismissView();
}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your code with some comments about what you're trying to achieve? I have some trouble understanding what you're doing and why you're doing it.

Comment: Kindly check the code now.

Comment: Ok... there is this project I am working on that requires me to get data fromt the same table and the update the record fetched earlier while looping through an array.

Comment: It work fine if the user didn't add same product more than ones but once the user add the same product more than two times, it only subtract the last quantity and skip others